# Do beta sites have different rep count requirements for privileges?

Tags: support, edits, privileges, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

According to the [privileges list](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), a user gains the ability to freely edit questions and answers at 2000 reputation.

But I have ~1400 rep on Writers.SE and French.SE and am able to freely edit questions and answers on both sites.

Is this because they're in beta, the rules are more lax? Where can I find a list of beta privilege requirements, if so?

Comment: http://writers.stackexchange.com/privileges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sites like Writers and French are still in the Beta phase.  They were sites that were proposed on Area 51, garnered enough support, and are actively trying to prove themselves to "graduate" into being a full site, on par with Stack Overflow and the dozens of other sites [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched).

Since these sites start from scratch, it's unfair to require users to have the reputation necessary to do things like edit (2000 rep on SO and graduated sites) and vote to close (3000 rep).  Many of these privileges are freely available to most users during the private beta, but after the private beta finishes they are brought up to the intermediate levels you see on the French faq (1000 rep to edit and 500 rep to vote to close).

So, [Jack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160115/159165) is at least partly correct, but the reputation requirements are not directly varied with traffic level, but instead with the status of the site on the Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

The privileges list is not the same for all sites on the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) network. Case in point if you look at the FAQ for the [http://french.stackexchange.com](https://french.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) site you'll see that you only need 1000 rep to edit questions.

Most likely the reason for this is because not all sites on the Stack Exchange network have the same amount of traffic, so on a lower traffic site it would make sense to have a lower rep requirement.

Comment: I did not realize that. I've never seen the other privilege lists before. Thanks.